# Linear Layout with Weights and Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I'm trying to create a responsive layout using weights but I also need to use a scroll view in this case.

This is my code at this moment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EncyclopediaFragment">

    <!--Linear Container-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <!--Title Box-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">

            <!--Empty Space-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5">


            </LinearLayout>

            <!--Text Box-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="95">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/encyclopedia_mosntersLabel"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

but it needs to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DZvy.png).

That layout is suppose to be responsive with weights but at the same time I need to make it possible to scroll.

So my question is: how can I create a layout responsive with weights and at the same time a layout that can scroll down, just like in the picture?

Comment: How many monster's and how many tower's ? I mean as a group? Is it one group of monster and one group of Tower[ as from image] ?

Comment: you can just put a layout inside the scroll view. I have previously used both grid layout and linear layout with weights for the exact same purpose.

Comment: Here's a partial tip.  For your monsters going across, I suggest a table row (width = match parent, gravity = center), each monster (width = 0dp, weight =1)..... do not use a weight sum.

Comment: It's suppose, per line, be 3 monsters and 3 towers. We have in total 6 monsters and 8 towers

Comment: @ArchiFloyd can you explain better?

Comment: Covered by the answer by Suhayl SH

Comment: Its not working. I have tried to create some buttons bigger than the weightSum but they do not show using scroll.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67829915/6314955 check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a determined number of 6 Monsters and 8 Towers, here is how you should organize your layout:

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Monsters"/>

            <!-- the following LinearLayout should be repeated twice for 6 Monsters -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <MonsterView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <MonsterView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <MonsterView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            ...


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Towers"/>        

            <!-- the following LinearLayout should be repeated twice for 6 Towers -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TowerView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TowerView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TowerView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            ...


            <!-- attention here for two Towers in the last row -->        

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <TowerView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <TowerView
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Ok, it works but how can I change the height of each TowerView or MonsterView in a responsive way?

Comment: You can define a `dimension` resource in values or dimens file: `<dimen name="monster_height">20dp</dimen>` and reference it inside `MonsterView` tag: `android:layout_height="@dimen/monster_height"`

Comment: So, there's no way using weights?

Comment: You don't need to use `weight` concept to control `MosterView`s `layout_height`. It cannot be combined with `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EncyclopediaFragment">

<!--Toolbar-->
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--Linear Container With Weights--> 

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is useless. The outer `RelativeLayout` does nothing. And the layout inside `ScrollView` should have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`.  Otherwise it makes no sense!

Answer (score 0):

The content inside your `ScrollView` should use `wrap_parent`, and if you want to stretch the content inside it set `android:fillViewport="true"`. Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".EncyclopediaFragment">

    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!--Linear Container--> 

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```